# Qual a melhor forma de esconder API Keys?

Tags: android, api

Quando você está compartilhando um repositório e não quer que a pessoa tenha acesso a chave de alguma API, qual a melhor forma de esconder?

Comment: Em um repositório de controle de versão (Git por exemplo)? Se for o caso, o melhor é você não enviar esse arquivo e adiciona-lo a lista de arquivos ignorados do Git (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: Exato.. Mas e se chave for usada dentro do código?

Comment: Se você está COMPARTILHANDO não vejo motivo para querer esconder, mas caso queira eu seguiria a dica do @vmartins sobre o gitgnore porém iria dá erro no seu código já que estará usando em tempo de execução a chave API. Acho que isso vai do bom senso da equipe de desenvolvedores desse projeto, se os outros dev não vão poder ter acesso é só não compartilhar ou cada um ter sua própria API key